# Java I/O stream

Tags: java, java-io

I am trying to copy the content of one file to another using Java I/O Stream.
I have written below code for this, but it is copying only the last letter of the source file.

```
   package io.file;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;


public class FileCopyTester {

    public void copyFile() {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try{
            fis = new FileInputStream("resources/Source.txt");
            System.out.println("Started copying");
            int data =  fis.read();

        while (data != -1){
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("resources/Destination.docx")){
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (IOException io) {
                System.err.println("Error o/p:"+io.getMessage());
            }
            System.out.print((char)data+" ");
            data = fis.read();
        }
        fis.close();
        System.out.println("End Copying");
        }

        catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println("ERROR: "+ioe.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileCopyTester().copyFile();
    }
}
```

In Source file I have data something like 
22
/
7
3.142857

So in destination I am getting only
7
Kindly help If I am missing something in this, like something that should not overwrite the data in destination file.

Comment: @ChrisThompson yea it was an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the stream at every turn of the loop is pointless - the new data is overwriting the old content of the file. However - opening the stream with the "append mode" will make your code work:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("resources/Destination.docx", true);
```

The second, nicer solution is to open the stream before loop:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("resources/Source.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("resources/Destination.docx");

int data = fis.read();
while (data != -1){
    fos.write(data);
    data = fis.read();
}

fos.close();
```

Comment: Also, create the streams in a try-with-resources

Answer (score 5):

You overwrite your file each time with one byte.

Solution: open the output stream outside your while loop, and close it afterwards.